# validate_email() does not verify emails other than gmail even though they exist

Tags: python, outlook

I've attempted to write a program in Python that takes email input, validates it using validate_email module and, if email is valid(means that it is written correctly and actually exists), it returns a message as valid. Otherwise, it outputs 'Not Valid' and attempts to get input again, until the email typed is valid. I tested by inputting email of different provider. However, even though this email address exists, the output is 'Not Valid' so I assume that validate_email() returns False. Here is the code:

```
from validate_email import validate_email

def verifyEmail(email):
    is_valid = validate_email(
    email=email, check_mx=True, verify=True,debug=True, smtp_timeout=10)
    verified = False
    if is_valid:
        verified = True
    else:
        verified = False
    return verified

to_addr = input("Please enter your email address here: ")
    
verified = verifyEmail(to_addr)
while verified == False:
    to_addr = input("Not valid. Enter a valid email address please:")
    verified = verifyEmail(to_addr)
if verified == True:
    print("This email is correctly written AND exists.")
```

I tested it and the output is:

> Please enter your email address here: megacaglar1304@outlook.com
>
> Not valid. Enter a valid email address please:mefecaglar361@gmail.com
>
> This email is correctly written AND exists.

Both emails exist and are correctly written but the output says "No, outlook email is not valid but the gmail one is OK".

What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe try  to get rid of whitespaces at the beginning or the end of the email-address by calling `verified = verifyEmail(to_addr.strip())` instead of `verified = verifyEmail(to_addr)`?

I don't see another problem with your code at the moment.

Unfortunatly I can not try it myself because I get errors when trying to install the module.

On a sidenote you can improve the readability of your code by simply doing:

```
from validate_email import validate_email

to_addr = input("Please enter your email address here: ").strip()
    
verified = validate_email(
to_addr, check_mx=True, verify=True, debug=True, smtp_timeout=10)

while not verified:
    to_addr = input("Not valid. Enter a valid email address please:").strip()
    verified = validate_email(
    to_addr, check_mx=True, verify=True, debug=True, smtp_timeout=10)

print("This email is correctly written AND exists.")
```

### Explaining the changes:

All your function `verifyEmail` did was return the value that `validate_email` returned previously, so you can skip having your own function for that.
If you still want to have it simply do:

```
def verifyEmail(email):
    return validate_email(
    email, check_mx=True, verify=True,debug=True, smtp_timeout=10)
```

Also you `while` condition can be reduced to `while not condition` instead of `while condition == False`.

Your `if` at the end will always be `True`, because to get there you need to exit the `while` in an orderly manner and therefore you can also delete it.

Comment: It gives the same result but thanks anyways!